# what is the difference among alloc ,copy and new?

Tags: ios4, memory-management

What are the actual difference among alloc,copy and new and also what about the assign and nonatomic Property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **alloc**

alloc is a Class selector (that is for exemple called like)

```
[NSObject alloc]
```

It returns a **non initialized** pointer of type NSObject*.

- **Init**

To complete the initialization, you must call the proper designated initializer on the **instance** itself:

```
[[NSObject alloc] init]
```

Will return a usable NSObject* pointer.

- **new**

The new basically does an alloc -> init except it is called directly at class level:

```
NSObject* aObj = [NSObject new]
NSObject* aObj = [[NSObject alloc] init]
```

Are similar.

- **nonatomic**

A nonatomic property means that when the property will be written (ex during a set call) **no lock will be added** on the variable synthesized by this property (that means no overkill time consuming @synchronize).

So if your property will not be changed by different threads simultaneously, you can safely set it to nonatomic.

- **copy**

A copy property means that when you modify that property ex:

```
aObj.copyProperty = otherValue
```

The *copyProperty* variable will send the copyWithZone: signal to the *otherValue* object.

In other words, if your *copyProperty* is compliant with the *NSCopying* protocol it will eventually have the same properties as *otherValue* but will have its own address and retain count and therefore be located at a totally different part of the memory as the *otherValue* was.

Basically *copyProperty* **will occupy as much memory** space as *otherValue*.

- **assign**

Assigning a property means that when you do:

```
aObj.prop = aProperty
```

The variable synthesized by the property *prop* will directly be assigned to aProperty meaning they will share exact **same address AND retain count**.

**No additional memory space** is occupied when you use assign.

I hope this helps you. For further information, please read the [Apple Memory Management Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)